# How can I access each text file in my own categorized corpus using a loop?

Tags: python, nlp, corpus

I'm a beginner in python, I use this line

```
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('~/CorpusMain/',
                                      r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*')
```

Inside my CorpusMain folder, I have further three folders for categories. I need to access each text file content in each category separately, building a list for each category containing text files as elements.. such as
category1 = ['textfile1 content', 'textfile2 content'...etc]
I want to do this using my reader, meaning to refer each file (fileids()) and get its reader.raw result...

I am needing this to feed those back to my CountVectorizer, to build a vector for each category..

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose something like `os.listdir` which will return the list of the content of the path specified as its argument.

An example:

For a directory structure like:

```
CorpusMain
├ text1.txt
└ text2.txt
```

text1.txt:

```
Text 1 content
```

text2.txt:

```
Text 2 content
```

The following code:

```
import os

def get_txt_content(path, txt):
    with open(path + r'\\' + txt, 'r') as text_file:
        return text_file.read()

def list_txt_content(path):
    textfiles = [_file for _file in os.listdir(path) if _file.endswith('.txt')]
    return [get_txt_content(path, txt) for txt in textfiles]

print list_txt_content(r'~/CorpusMain')
```

Will generate a list like this:

```
['Text 1 content', 'Text 2 content']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually want to build a corpus array with each element of it containing a single file, for example : corpus = [ 'this is text file1 content', 'this is text file 2 content' .... ], so I want the raw data of my reader files...

Comment: So you just want to list the content of each text file in a specific folder?

Comment: I have fixed it. Thank you very much for your help! :D